# Cannot alter system32 under Windows domain enviroment?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, windows-domain

I'm using local admin to login to domain workstation under Windows 7. I want to delete opengl32.dll or replace it, but don't have the permission to do so.

The location of file is **/system32**

Where are the gpo settings where I can override this change?

Comment: If you are a domain user the you would require administrator on the domain level.  The local administrator enables very little in a domain environment

Comment: @Ramhound does the local admin privilegs override the domain user?

Comment: can I ask why?  you do not generally delete files from system32.

Comment: @asadz the domain overrides the local settings

Comment: @Ramhound but not in case; you have rights to change the group policy settings (gpedit.msc) my problem is I cannot find where these settings are .dll files under use.

Comment: You can change the local group but not the domain group. All goedit does is modify the registry.  But your inability to delete the file in question unlikely has anything to do with your user permissions

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot delete the file Opengl32.dll is because it is likely to be currently in use, not because you do not have access rights. Sometimes the wrong error message is being given.

Try closing any programs that might be using opengl32.dll or boot into savemode before trying again.

Additionally, sometimes deleting or renaming a file while in the command prompt does work while it doesn't in the explorer window. This is often when windows thinks a file is in use while it really is not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to UAC:

```
1. Goto Control Panel
2. User Accounts
3. Change User Account Control Settings and change the bar to Default if it's "Always Notify"
```